# itunes connect forget something

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I've submit my app to approval process, my app is in review, when go see the details i see that to "Bundle short string" or something similar is empty.

Will it be rejected?

Comment: This is a question about Apple's iTunes Connect site, so it might be more appropriate to ask at their developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

My "Bundle Short Version String" is blank and my app got accepted, so I think you might be OK. But, I might get rejected the next time around if I don't fix it, hard to say unless someone has been rejected for not having it.